# an infinite product identity

Tags: real-analysis

I encountered the following post on a website (www.quora.com) I quote the post verbatim-these are not my comments.

"Why is the number "42" so significant to mathematicians?

It is for the very simple reason that:
$$42^{\frac{382835430481}{625000000000}}=6{\prod}_{p\ {\rm{Prime}}}{\frac{1}{1-{\frac{1}{p^2}}}}.$$
This is a very deep result, whose impact we do not yet fully understand."

I do not believe that this identity is true. Here is my reasoning. The right hand side is $6{\zeta}(2)={\pi}^2$. The left hand side on the other hand is of the form $42^{\frac{m}{n}}$ where $m$ and $n$ are both positive integers. If such an identity were true than we would be forced to conclude (raising both sides to the $n$-th power) that $$42^{m}={\pi}^{2n}.$$This would imply that $\pi$ is an algebraic integer, being a root of the polynomial $f(x)= {x^{2n}}-42^{m}\in{{\bf Z}[x]}.$ But this contradicts the fact that $\pi$ is a transcendental number. Am I missing something here? The reason I ask is that the author of the post seems to think that I am mistaken, but refuses to furnish a reason! Appreciate your thoughts!

Comment: It is news to me that $42$ is specially significant to anyone outside of what amounts to dead memes these days.

Comment: This is because that identity is probably (definitely) not true. Troll?

Comment: The person who posted it it was combative : I have a post-graduate degree in Pure Mathematics (sadly a lowly Masters), what is the likelihood that I know the difference between an algebraic and a transcendental number?

In either case, I think a good rule is “think before you comment”. Of course it is true, are you suggesting that my decades of work on this equality are erroneous?

Comment: @EeveeTrainer: Whats wrong with fans of Douglas Adams?

Comment: This seems like either a troll or the misguided victim of trolling. Close?

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=42%5E%28382835430481%2F625000000000%29+-+pi%5E2) gives the difference between that power of $42$ and $\pi^2$ to be about $-7.61 \times 10^{-12}$. My guess is it's just a close-miss troll attempt - not unlike the Fermat's Last Theorem near-miss contradictions seen often in The Simpson's - to get people antsy. He probably had some method of approximating it, and used this to play a joke on people.

Comment: "Whats wrong with fans of Douglas Adams?" -- Nothing at all xD

Comment: @student It is proven that $\pi$ is transcendental, so until I see a proof of that unlikely identity of yours, I’m going to say it’s probably false.

Comment: Sorry guys! I guess I deserve being trolled! I fell for it!

Comment: $\color{red}{42}$ is important to everyone (not only mathematicians) since it is *"The "Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything"*. Just have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/42_(number)#cite_note-18

Answer (score 4):

Just to continue the joke, whatever could be the rhs (say $k$) you always can write
$$42^x=k \implies x=\frac{\log (k)}{\log (42)}$$ and find the closest rational number you want for a given accuracy.

For $k=\pi^2$ as in your example, take
$$x=\frac{113324902276818252177817587796556698968660872730811}{185009166560153907338903
   184470209689295067534049020}$$ and you will have $100$ correct significant figures.

For $k=e$, use
$$x=\frac{14286931922365270336190072861145109626110493519818}{5339983138470746932953829
   5633396756354619740280665}$$

For $k=\zeta (3)$, use
$$x=\frac{4984293073556644693450328273976834743385651648058}{10122924587252622722204541
   3352905624410070072168739}$$